# Migration application from Applet

Tags: internet-explorer, applet, internet-explorer-11

Our application runs on Java applet, we are planning to migrate from Applet, but not before 2019
Please let me know if Applet IE 11 compatibility plugin can get removed in near future or not.
How long APIs needed to support Applets in Internet Explorer 11 will be available?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, about which Applet IE 11 compatibility plugin you are talking here.

There is a setting in Internet Explorer options. If you enable it than you will be able to run the JAVA Applet. This setting will remain there and it will not get removed from IE 11.

You can refer the steps below to enable JAVA Applet scripting in IE.

(1) Click Tools and then Internet Options

(2) Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button

(3) Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets

(4) Make sure the Enable radio button is checked

(5) Click OK to save your preference

[image]